# CAST and CONCAT inside INSERT

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Using an Oracle database :

How can I use a concatenation and cast inside an INSERT statement ?

I need to insert data for some tests, and I need to change the ID of the inserted data.

So far, I got this :

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 100..400 LOOP
      INSERT INTO PRESTATION 
      (ID_DEMANDE, ID_PRESTATION, CODE_PRODUCTEUR_UNICITE_PRESTA, SELECTION, ID_RUBRIQUE, LIBELLE_CONTRAT, CODE_PRODUCTEUR_ENTITE_JURIDIQ, GUICHET_GESTIONNAIRE, CODE_SOURCE, CODE_PRODUIT, CODE_SOUS_PRODUIT, LIBELLE_PRODUIT, CODE_BANQUE, NUMERO_CLIENT, MONTANT, DEVISE, RESEAU_DISTRIBUTION, DATE_OUVERTURE, DATE_FERMETURE, ROLE) 
      VALUES 
      ('DO20161220160056000592', CONCAT('0000000317501820134', CAST(i AS VARCHAR)), '00020', 'O', 0, 'COMPTE  COURANT', '30003', '03175', '001', '020', '001', 'COMPTE D ENTREPRISE', '30003', '00000013419', '4242,420', 'EUR', '10', '27/01/93', '31/12/99', '10');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

I probably need to add a SELECT somewhere.

Or there's probably a better way to generate those IDs...

Comment: Your issue? Have an error?

Comment: Instead of `CONCAT('0000000317501820134', CAST(i AS VARCHAR))` you can use shorter `'0000000317501820134'||i`.

Comment: You insert **number** as strings (e.g. '4242,420') and **date** as strings (e.g. '27/01/93') - even with two digits for year. I bet sooner or later you will face many problems due to such poor design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..400 LOOP
      INSERT INTO PRESTATION 
      (ID_DEMANDE, ID_PRESTATION, CODE_PRODUCTEUR_UNICITE_PRESTA, SELECTION, ID_RUBRIQUE, LIBELLE_CONTRAT, CODE_PRODUCTEUR_ENTITE_JURIDIQ, GUICHET_GESTIONNAIRE, CODE_SOURCE, CODE_PRODUIT, CODE_SOUS_PRODUIT, LIBELLE_PRODUIT, CODE_BANQUE, NUMERO_CLIENT, MONTANT, DEVISE, RESEAU_DISTRIBUTION, DATE_OUVERTURE, DATE_FERMETURE, ROLE) 
      VALUES 
      ('DO20161220160056000592', '0000000317501820134'||''||i||'', '00020', 'O', 0, 'COMPTE  COURANT', '30003', '03175', '001', '020', '001', 'COMPTE D ENTREPRISE', '30003', '00000013419', '4242,420', 'EUR', '10', '27/01/93', '31/12/99', '10');
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Demo:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..4 LOOP
      dbms_output.put_line ('0000000317501820134'||''||i||'');
  END LOOP;
 END;    
 /
00000003175018201341
00000003175018201342
00000003175018201343
00000003175018201344

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: Sweet, what is the `||` operator exactly ?

Comment: This is used for concatenting. Either you can use word `concat` or `||`.

Comment: But why the empty string `''` then ? I would have thought it should be `'''` i norder to wrap quotes around the number i.

Comment: You can remove it. I just kept it for your understanding. you can remove it and the result remians the same.

Comment: @Ellone just for your understanding, there is no such concept as the empty string in Oracle - `''` evaluates to null.

Comment: @Boneist - That depends on one's definition of "empty string" and "null". In this example, `''` actually behaves as an empty string. It is only in Oracle that an operation where one operand is "null" has a result that is anything other than "null". It is best when using Oracle to think that `''` is sometimes treated as an empty string and sometimes as "null" (and not always in a consistent way).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive cte to generate the numbers and then `concatenate` them in one of the columns.

```
INSERT INTO PRESTATION 
  (ID_DEMANDE, ID_PRESTATION, CODE_PRODUCTEUR_UNICITE_PRESTA, SELECTION, ID_RUBRIQUE, LIBELLE_CONTRAT, CODE_PRODUCTEUR_ENTITE_JURIDIQ, GUICHET_GESTIONNAIRE, CODE_SOURCE, CODE_PRODUIT, CODE_SOUS_PRODUIT, LIBELLE_PRODUIT, CODE_BANQUE, NUMERO_CLIENT, MONTANT, DEVISE, RESEAU_DISTRIBUTION, DATE_OUVERTURE, DATE_FERMETURE, ROLE) 
with nums(num) as (select 100 from dual
                   union all
                   select num+1 from nums where num < 400)
SELECT 'DO20161220160056000592', CONCAT('0000000317501820134', CAST(num AS VARCHAR(3))), '00020', 'O', 0, 'COMPTE  COURANT', '30003', '03175', '001', '020', '001', 'COMPTE D ENTREPRISE', '30003', '00000013419', '4242,420', 'EUR', '10', '27/01/93', '31/12/99', '10'
FROM nums
```

Comment: This gets me a "missing select keyword" error at the insert line. Where should it be ? (I'm using SQLDeveloper)

Comment: the recursive cte comes after `insert`. i changed it.

Comment: This approach has the advantage that everything is done in plain SQL. PL/SQL (procedures, triggers, functions) should be used only when plain SQL won't work, and this isn't one of those cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to insert many rows into a table, where only some fields are varying, you can use something like this:

```
SQL> create table yourTable ( col1 varchar2(20), col2 varchar2(20), col3 varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into yourTable ( col1, col2, col3)
  2    select 'fixedValue', 'fixedValue2', 100 + level
  3    from dual
  4    connect by level <= 10;

10 rows created.

SQL> select * from yourTable;

COL1                 COL2                 COL3
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
fixedValue           fixedValue2          101
fixedValue           fixedValue2          102
fixedValue           fixedValue2          103
fixedValue           fixedValue2          104
fixedValue           fixedValue2          105
fixedValue           fixedValue2          106
fixedValue           fixedValue2          107
fixedValue           fixedValue2          108
fixedValue           fixedValue2          109
fixedValue           fixedValue2          110

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```